# Is the sum of two negligible sets always a negligible set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ and $F$ be two negligible sets, is the following sum always a negligible set?

$E + F = \{x + y : x ∈
E, y ∈ F\}$

I tend to say no but I can't find any counter exemple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general no. For instance, if $C$ is the Cantor set, then $C+C=[0,2]$.

Comment: Thank you, I also found that the sum of the x-axis and the y-axis is equal to the whole plane for a more simple example